# android - save button clicking opens first activity rather than saving

Tags: android, xamarin, save

I am using xamarin in visual studio 2015. I have an activity that has editexts, radio buttons, checkboxes and a save button. when the save button is clicked, the values in the controls are posted back to a webservice in my server that saves them and sends back a confirmation. I show the confirmation message as toast to the user. This works correctly in the xamarin android player. But, when i install it in my phone it does not work. Clicking the save button opens the first activity in the app. Also the global variables are lost.
Can someone please help. Thanks

Comment: share your code

Comment: Without any code , how can  we help?

Comment: Debug using your device, and make use of breakpoints.

Comment: Thank you @Vaikesh. As u said, I used my devicedirectly to debug and immediately caught the error. It was actually a datetime format error. Thanks